# Popping pentominoes

Tags: mathematics, tiling

I started with the following configuration:

[image]

I then popped a few spots in the shape of the same [pentomino](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) to arrive at this configuration:

[image]

The shapes did not overlap and I was allowed to rotate and mirror them. Which pentomino could I have used?

<sub>Image transcript:</sub>

```
○○○○○○    ○○●●○○
○○○○○○    ○●●●○○
○○○○○○    ○●●●●●
○○○○○○    ○●●●●●
○○○○○○    ●●●●●○
○○○○○○    ●●●●●○
 Figure1       Figure2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have used a

> P pentomino.

Like this

> ```
>  • • # # • •
>  • # # # • •
>  • @ @ @ # #
>  • @ @ # # #
>  # # # @ @ •
>  # # @ @ @ •
> ```

And this is just one example configuration.

Some other configurations are

> ```
>  • • # # • •       • • # # • •
>  • @ # # • •       • # # # • •
>  • @ @ # & &       • @ @ @ # #
>  • @ @ & & &  and  • # @ @ # #
>  # # # @ @ •       # # & & # •
>  # # @ @ @ •       # # & & & •
> ```

More examples can be derived by rearranging certain rows of these three.

Comment: Could any other pentomino be used?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I didn't find one. Basically it was trial and error, fortunately the fitting answer was found early. Due to first row and last column, many other shapes can be omitted at the first place.

Answer (score 4):

An answer by process of elimination:

> The dots are on the squares one of the shapes needs to have. Dark red and pink both denote a distinct possible placement, with red meaning only one possible placement or squares covered both by light and dark placements. I omitted some trivial cases and placements making the solution impossible in the first place by directly blocking off part of the board: 
> [image]

A more elegant solution can be this (crosses are the colors ruled out for the cell).

> [image]

Comment: I don't want to attack any other user, but I'd wager that if I were the one posted the answer above, it would have rained downvotes because "AnSwEr nOt ExPlAiNeD!". I have nothing against any users, I'm just frustrated about the double standards.